# Is It Possible To Use PrimeFaces Charts In Pure Java?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a spring-boot project. And I want to create dynamic chart images via api endpoints. Primefaces provides charts (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chartjs/pie.xhtml)

In here, I wonder that I can handle it with only using pure java?

Then I want to present it via java servlet like:

```
...
ImageIO.write(chart, "png", output);
return output.toByteArray();
```

**Note:** I don't have any front-end code. Only I have pure java code with spring-boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isnt possible as it uses JS / ChartJS: https://www.chartjs.org/